# Merging two tables the rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 with ActiveRecord, ruby 1.8.6, mysql (2.8.1)

I have two tables A and B with the exact same column structures.  A is on a separate server from B.

I want to take the entire contents of B and add them to A so

A = A + B

Any elegant methods?  I thought about taking one record at a time from B and just adding it into A, but that doesn't seem that great..

Comment: I know that most newcomers to Rails don't recognize the difference, but am I correct in assuming that you're using ActiveRecord with Rails, and not some other ORM such as Sequel or DataMapper?

Comment: Yeah I'm using ActiveRecord with Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To permanently copy the contents of one table to another you'll need a variation of the INSERT query syntax. You don't specify which RDBMS you're using so I'll just go ahead and show how it'd work with MySQL.

```
INSERT A SELECT * FROM B
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

**EDIT**

If your tables are hosted on separate servers you'll need to copy one of them so they're on the same MySQL instance. That can be done with the `mysqldump` and `mysql` commands, like:

```
mysqldump -h <hostname> <database_name> <table_name> |mysql -h <other_hostname> <other_database_name>
```

*or, if you prefer to use ssh*

```
ssh <hostname> mysqldump <database_name> <table_name> |ssh <other_hostname> mysql <other_database_name>
```

Comment: Hmm this is a newbie question . What if the tables are on different databases?

Comment: No problem, just specify it as `INSERT DB1.A SELECT * FROM DB2.B` ..that is assuming you mean different databases *on the same server*.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point.. what if they're on different servers?

Comment: You haven't told us what database software you're using yet. It's hard to answer questions like these in the abstract all the time.. We (@coreyward, @Phrogz) already mistook your original question for meaning that you just wanted a temporary UNION query. Could you try being more specific? Update your question if possible too rather than carrying on this conversation in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question.  Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this two places, your SQL, or in your application.

Through a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_b;
```

In your Rails application:

```
a = A.all
b = B.all
ab = a + b
```

Simple enough.

**UPDATE:** 
Since you want to make this change permanently, you should create a migration that will merge the two tables together. This will make sure Rails knows what's going on, and it will allow you to migrate your production database similarly. Because ActiveRecord doesn't have a built-in table merge, you would execute a raw SQL query in your migration like so:

```
class MergeTableAWithTableB < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "INSERT INTO `table_a` (field_1, field_2, field_3) SELECT (field_1, field_2, field_3) FROM `table_b`;"
    drop_table :table_b
  end

  def self.down
    raise IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` at the command line to have this action performed.

This has the effect of re-indexing the rows from table_b, though, since moving them over to table_a would result in conflicting primary ids.

Comment: I think (s)he wants to do `INSERT SELECT ...` to concatenate the tables permanently, not just "join" them in a query.

Comment: Thanks! Would I run into any problems if I have millions of entries in each table?

Comment: If you're doing anything with millions of rows being loaded in memory, yes, you will have performance issues. In order to do something like this in a performance-minded way you should use streaming or chunk the task into pieces.

Comment: To permanently modify the tables, you should create a migration. I'll update my answer…

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ActiveRecord (unlike [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/index.html)) does not support batch insert by default. Look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284962/efficient-bulk-update-rails-database/2286377#2286377) for a library that extends ActiveRecord so that you can do a single efficient update rather than one SQL insert for each row.