# Updating a lot of records frequently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails 3 app that has several hundred records in a mySQL-DB that need to be updated multiple times each hour. The actual updating is done through `delayed_job` which is triggered in controller-logic (checking if enough time has passed since the last update, only then sth. happens).

Each update is slow, it can take up to a second in some cases (although it averages at 3 - 5 updates/sec.). 
Code looks like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

...

  def self.scheduled_update
    Thing.all.each do |t|
      ...
      t.some_property = new_value
      t.save
    end
  end 

end
```

I've observed that the execution stalls after 300 - 400 records and then the delayed job just seems to hang and times out eventually (entries in `delayed_job.log`). After a while the next one starts, also fails, and so forth, so not all records get updated.

What is the proper way to do this?

How does Rails handle database-connections when used like that? Could it be some timeout issue that is not detected/handled properly?

There must be a default way to do this, but couldn't find anything so far..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look at this, it can really help to speed up your mass updates http://stackoverflow.com/a/2286377/1241447

Answer (score 2):

Another options is [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

Comment: Thank you nbsp, but the solution was different. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is a bad choice for mass data records.  See if you can create a sql stored procedure or some other way that would avoid active record.

- Use `object.save_with_validation(false)` if you are ok with skipping validations altogether.
- When finding records, use `:select => 'a,b,c,other_fields'` to limit the fields you want ('a', 'b', 'c' and 'other' in this example).
- Use `:include` for eager loading when you are initially selecting and joining across multiple tables.

Comment: You might want to recheck the docs on save_with_validation because it takes an options hash, not a boolean.

Comment: Thank you, but the solution was different. See below.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem.

There was some issue with the rails-version I was using (3.0.3), the Timeout was caused by some bug I suspect. Updating to a later version of the 3.0.x branch solved it and everything runs perfectly now.